# iAds not showing on device after release to App Store?

Tags: swift, iad

I have recently released my game to the App Store. The iAd banner and medium ads are not showing up after almost a week now. All its showing isa blank space as in the following screenshots.

Can anyone check if there is anything wrong with my iAd code?

Before Release:
[image: Before Release Screenshot]

After Release:
[image: After Release Screenshot]

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import iAd
import Social
import GameKit
import StoreKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate, ADInterstitialAdDelegate {
var scene: GameScene!

@IBOutlet var bannerView: ADBannerView!
var imageView = UIImageView()
var interAd = ADInterstitialAd()
var mediumRectAdView = ADBannerView(adType: ADAdType.MediumRectangle)
var interAdView = UIView()
var closeButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let screenBounds: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    bannerView = ADBannerView(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,screenBounds.width))
    bannerView.center = CGPoint(x: screenBounds.width/2, y:screenBounds.height-bannerView.frame.size.height/2)
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.hidden = false//false //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,

    scene = GameScene(size:CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536))
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
    skView.addSubview(bannerView)
    if scene.productPurchased == true {
        bannerView.hidden = true
    }    
    firstScene = false

    //self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.Manual

    //Authenticate Game Center
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:#selector(GameViewController.showAuthenticationViewController),name:PresentAuthenticationViewController, object: nil)
    SGGameKit.sharedInstance.authenticateLocalPlayer()

    // Share
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: (#selector(GameViewController.displayShareSheet)), name:mySharePostKey, object: nil)

    // Med iAD
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: (#selector(GameViewController.loadMedAd)), name:myloadMedAdKey, object: nil)

    // Interstitial iAD
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: (#selector(GameViewController.loadInterAd)), name:myloadInterAdKey, object: nil)

    // Hide Iad
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: (#selector(GameViewController.hideAd)), name:myHideAdKey, object: nil)
}

func hideAd() {
    print("Hiding Ad")
    bannerView.hidden = true
}

func displayShareSheet() {

    let initialText = "OMG! I got \(scene.score) points in Jumpox\n" + "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id1099659993)"
    if let myImage =  self.view?.pb_takeSnapshot() {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, nil, nil, nil)
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [initialText,myImage as UIImage], applicationActivities: [])
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks]

        if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone {
            self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
        }
        else {
            let popup: UIPopoverController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController:activityViewController)
            popup.presentPopoverFromRect(CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 4, 0, 0), inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

func loadMedAd() {

    print("Loading loadMedAd")
    closeButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 30, 30)
    closeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    closeButton.setTitle("X", forState: .Normal)
    closeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    closeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    closeButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    closeButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameViewController.close), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)

    mediumRectAdView!.delegate = self
    mediumRectAdView.center = self.view.center
    mediumRectAdView.addSubview(closeButton)

    interAdView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
    self.view.addSubview(interAdView)

    interAdView.addSubview(mediumRectAdView)
}

func loadInterAd() {

    print("Loading loadInterAd")

    interAd = ADInterstitialAd()
    interAd.delegate = self

    //if interAd.loaded {
        closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 40, 40)
        closeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        closeButton.setTitle("X", forState: .Normal)
        closeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        closeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        closeButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        closeButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameViewController.close), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)

        interAdView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
        interAdView.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(interAdView)

        interAd.presentInView(interAdView)
        interAdView.addSubview(closeButton)
    //}

    //requestInterstitialAdPresentation()
}

func interstitialAd(interAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {

    print("Failed To Receive")
    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interAdView.removeFromSuperview()
}

func close() {

    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interAdView.removeFromSuperview()
}

func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func showAuthenticationViewController() {

    let gameKitHelper = SGGameKit.sharedInstance
    if let authenticationViewController = gameKitHelper.authenticationViewController {
        self.presentViewController(authenticationViewController, animated: true,
                                   completion: nil)
    }
}

func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController){
    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[iAd has been discontinued](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a) and is not accepting new apps into the network.

> The iAd App Network will be discontinued as of June 30, 2016. Although
>   we are no longer accepting new apps into the network, advertising
>   campaigns may continue to run and you can still earn advertising
>   revenue until June 30. If you’d like to continue promoting your apps
>   through iAd until then, you can create a campaign using iAd Workbench.

I'm surprised the reviewer did not reject your submission. Look into AdMob, AppLovin, or the many other ad networks available for iOS.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just opted to use AdMob and am submitting the game  now. Hope there will be no issue

Comment: @BinhHuynh my pleasure. Feel free to accept my answer if it helped you.