# How can I get my iAd interstitial to work

Tags: swift, iad

I've looked everywhere for this but I can't find it. I've checked the code and it works in the simulator but not on the real app on the App Store. I launched the app which used this ad code way back in January and the adverts are still not working, all the billing and stuff is filled in on iTunes connect, I don't know how to fix it.

This is my code for the ads:

```
func loadInterstitialAd() {
    interstitialAd = ADInterstitialAd()
    interstitialAd.delegate = self
}

func interstitialAdWillLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {

}

func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    interstitialAdView = UIView()
    interstitialAdView.frame = self.view!.bounds
    view!.addSubview(interstitialAdView)

    interstitialAd.presentInView(interstitialAdView)
    UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
}

func interstitialAdActionDidFinish(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()
}

func interstitialAdActionShouldBegin(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {

}

func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Just a side note if you didn't already know, the iAd network is being discontinued and will no longer generate revenue at the end of June.

Comment: Oh no, that's annoying, what other services can be used for advertising in apps? Thanks

Comment: Related: [iAds not showing on device after release to App Store?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37032881/2108547)

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what's wrong with it